# PHP: What is the rule governing the maximum font size for imagettftext(...)?

Tags: php, fonts, size, gd

I downloaded a ttf font: [fontsquirrel.com/fonts/FFF-Tusj](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/FFF-Tusj) and applied it to an image using [imagettftext](http://php.net/imagettftext).

It seems that as I push the font size up towards 60, 70, 80 that I am not seeing any apparent changes.

Is there a maximum font-size? And if so, what is controlling it? Is it the .ttf file?? Is it the `imagettftext(...)` method??